# Can I use the Stanford-nlp ner project to parse names of different formats?

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I might be barking up the wrong tree: is it possible to use the Stanford-nlp Named Entity Recognition application to parse names that have wildly-different formats?

I'm using the NuGet version of said app in a c# application, as described in this link:  http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordNER.html, and the english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz model.

The Name field that I need to parse might contain any of these values:

- Joe Jones
- Joe Jones, Jane Jones
- Joe & Jane Jones
- Joe and Jane Jones
- Jones, Joe
- Jones, Joe and Jane

Using the english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz model, Stanford-nlp NER handles the first two fine, putting them correctly into their own PERSON nodes, but not the rest.

Is there a model file out there I could use that would do a more thorough job of parsing names?

Comment: I think you should incline to `Python` when trying with `NLP`.